# How to keep order provided in "in" clause in Spring Data JPA or Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a pretty simple query which retrieves values base on "in" clause. List that comes as "in" argument is appropriately sorted.

Query :

```
@Query(value = "select i from ItemEntity i where i.secondaryId in :ids")
List<ItemEntity> itemsIn(@Param("ids") List<UUID> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

I need results to be ordered the same way as `List<UUID> ids`, is it possible to achieve this without plain sql but only with the help of `Spring Data` and/or `Hibernate`.

Comment: Even with plain SQL, I don't see how you could do that. You'll need to sort the returned list by comparing the item entities by the position of their ID in the list of ids.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that by JPA too but you will have to create a comma separated list of ids in the order you want. In your case you can keep same order.

```
@Query(value = "select i from ItemEntity i where i.secondaryId in :ids 
       order by FIND_IN_SET(i.secondaryId, :idStr)")
List<ItemEntity> itemsIn(@Param("ids") List<UUID> ids, @Param("idStr") String idStr);
```

To create comma separated list you can java 8 stream:

```
ids.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Example:

```
SELECT id FROM User WHERE id in (2,3,1) 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,"2,3,1");
```

Result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  1 |
+----+
```

There is also one alternative using JPQL:

```
You can use ,,FIELD'' instead of ,,FIND_IN_SET ''.
```

You can find the example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65943906/15101302

Comment: this is returning "ERROR: function find_in_set(bigint, character varying) does not exist", where the 'u' come from in u.secondaryId? Is it supposed to be a string?

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` doesn't seem to be a JPQL construct (but MySQL).