# how to stop @query in jpa having IN clause from ordering by id?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have to fetch list of records from database by passing 2 parameters namely 
1st parameter is Object type and 2nd parameter is Collection.

@Query("select cnt from Content cnt where cnt.studio=?1 and cnt.id IN ?2")

public List getUpdatePlaylistTypeContent(Studio studio,List contentids);

So, in my above mentioned code, the IN clause is automatically implementing order by id asc though i have not mentioned.I want to stop the implicit order by clause.

I want the result list in the same manner as i am passing in the list object (2nd method paramater)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep order provided in "in" clause in Spring Data JPA or Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039698/how-to-keep-order-provided-in-in-clause-in-spring-data-jpa-or-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated SQL (with eg. `show_sql=true`) and I'm sure you won't see any `ORDER BY` clause.

But, if you run the same SQL on the database, results will be ordered by ID if there is an index (eg. primary key) with default settings on the id column.

Eg. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-ordering.html

From a database point of view, the result is more like a set than a list, so you need to order it explicitly (or be happy with index ordering). You can't rely on anything you're putting in the where clause to sort the results, so you'll need further processing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related with JPA, try your sql in your database. It would shou you the same order.
Check your database type for forbidding the in auto sort;

Oracle

```
SELECT * FROM table where id IN (3,2,5,1,4) ORDER BY DECODE(id, 3,1,2,2,5,3,1,4) 
//you need the *,1,*,2,*,3,*,*
```

Mysql

```
select * from table where id IN (3,9,6) order by field(id,3,9,6)
```

I did not test the mysql one, but it should work well